# am i allow parsing(getting) content from a facebook page

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to extract Facebook members name with preg_match from graph.facebook.com, by userID.

The script doesn't seem to be working. can anyone help?

```
<?php   
$content = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/myid?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,picture');

preg_match("'\"name\": \"(.*?)\",'si", $content, $match);
$name = $match[1];

?>
```

Comment: You need to use a JSON parser.

Comment: You'll need to ask FB - only they can give you a legally valid answer.

Comment: in general, why would you want to parse data from a page you don´t own? that´s surely not allowed, especially if you want to present that data somewhere else.

Comment: no. page owner allowed me. and i want to build a script for getting datas daily. and i want to parse only one page. what do you think about it

Comment: You need to use the Facebook API.

Comment: if the page owner allowed it, it´s no problem. but you MUST use the graph api, you are not allowed to "scrape" things.

Comment: hey i want a reference(resource). I should show the answer to my boss

Comment: Here are the scraping policy that say that you can't scrape without written permission from Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: If any of you above had read the question you would see that the URL he is getting is using the `graphAPI`. He is just using the API incorrectly. See my answer below in a second.

Comment: hey i Want to know am i allow to save and collect data and store them in a database using graph api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is make use of the PHP SDK for the Graph API that Facebook provides for you to use.

The API requires for you to setup tokens to determine you are who you say you are and also that the data you request is sent securely. These are all documented within Facebook's own API documentation for the API.

Start building your app using the PHP SDK and Graph and see where you get to, it would be better to try and figure out how to use it all yourself so you know for future reference than just getting someone to do the work for you.

An example of using the API is below:

```
/* PHP SDK v4.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/me'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

PHP SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0?locale=en_GB

General API Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api?locale=en_GB